# How can I located element in selenium using the following element?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find the following element in selenium[image]

It is a user name input field and I use: loginLink = driver.find_element(By.name, "loginEmail" but keep getting "no such element" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//input[@ng-reflect-name='loginEmail']
```

Use xpath or CSS , you can find by name only if the attribute key is 'name'

Eg 'name=loginEmail'

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@ng-reflect-name='loginEmail']")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[ng-reflect-name='loginEmail']")
```

you can use xpath and css for any attribute as

xpath: `//tagname[@attriubute='value']`
css: `tagname[attriubute='value']`

Answer (score 0):

Using the xpath given by PDHide the code you need to use is

`loginLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@ng-reflect-name='loginEmail']")`